# Horizontal offset on external monitor

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, hdmi

A friend is trying to connect a Surface Pro tablet to a external monitor (Samsung Syncmaster). The monitor is a little dated and has only a DVI input, but came with a HMDI-to-DVI adapter. The monitor worked fine so far with any laptop or PC via any HDMI cable we tried.

We got a USB-C-to-HDMI cable to connect the Surface Pro. But when we connect it, the shown image is horizontally so far off, that it kinda enters from the other side again. So the image is basically split at about 2/3, and the left side is on the right and vice versa, with a black bar dividing the two. I added a sketch below:

[image]

The screen is displayed fine on the Surface itself. And any combination of other laptops, monitors, and adapters works as well. So all involved parts work. But the combination of this one monitor and the tablet does somehow not seem to work.

I already tried updating all the drivers and changed the frequency and resolution to different settings. with no success. I couldn't find any more knobs to turn.

**Additional information:**

The monitor is a Samsung SyncMaster P2370.

I tried to "move" the image with the monitor menu, but there are no settings for that. V- and H-Position are grayed out. According to the manual, these settings are only available in the "analog" mode. However I cannot switch to an analog mode. It's either digital mode or nothing (black screen and not even the OSD message "Analog input"). See below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The monitor itself has a control panel. Use that to adjust horizontal position, aspect ratio, or possibly timing or sync.

- Download the Samsung Syncmaster manual.
- Turn to page 43.
- Adjust *H-Position* as shown below.

[image: H-Position adj.]

You might *also* need to adjust the aspect ratio, as shown on p. 47

Comment: I tried that, see my update to the question